# AWS API gateway giving 400 bad request error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using API gateway + JWT based authorization to secure my AWS lambda functions. I am able to get correct policy in my aws console for the authorizer. The lambda function I am trying to access is working fine separately. It's working fine when I change authorization to none for `GET_CUSTOMERS_URI` and I get data. But when combined together using API gateway, it's giving 400 bad request errors. I understand this has something to do with how the request is being made from the front-end but I am unable to figure that out.

My fetch request looks like this[React app]:-

```
return await fetch(GET_CUSTOMERS_URI, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors', 
  cache: 'no-cache', 
  credentials: 'same-origin', 
  headers: {
      'authorizationToken': 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
  referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',

})
```

Policy returned from the authorizer(tested using the AWS console):-

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:<account id>:<api id>/<stage-name>/GET/customers"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Kindly turn on execution logging on API Gateway and share what the error describes. Also share a snippet of the Lambda execution log if there is any. I can only assist depending on what the logs is describing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I have solved the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a CORS error. I solved this by:-

1. Select an endpoint in the API gateway.
2. Click `Actions` -> `Enable CORS`
3. Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` field to all values separated by comma, you are passing as header from front-end
4. Click `Enable CORS and replace existing CORS headers` button